# Linear algebra problem(straight line)

Tags: linear-algebra

problem:
The set of solutions for the following equation system is a straight line. Find a point on the line and a direction vector for the line.
$$
        \left(\begin{matrix}
        6 & 1 & -1 & -2 \\
        -7 & 3 & 2 & 19\\
        8 & 3 & -1 & 4 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$
which simplifies to:

$$
        \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & -0.2 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0.2 & 4\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$
$z = t$;

so $$ x = -1 + 0.2t $$
$$ y = 4 - 0.2t $$
$$ z = t$$

My book says the point is $(-1, 4 , 1)$ and the direction vector is $(1, -1, 5)$.
But shouldn't the direction vector be $(0.2, -0.2, 1)$ instead.

What am i missing?

Comment: If $\vec{v}$ is a direction vector, then $\lambda\cdot\vec{v}$ is also a direction vector for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}_{0}$. Here, $(1,-1,5)=5\cdot(0.2,-0.2,1)$, so both answers are ok (I did not check the details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectors $(1,-1,5)$ and $(0.2,-0.2,1)$ point in the same direction.

The second vector is $0.2$ times the first, so they differ only in length.

Comment: Aha, so direction vector means we don't care about length...makes sense

Comment: Yes, note that the problem asked for "a direction vector", not "the direction vector". However, you can standardize it somewhat by dividing by its length to get a unit direction vector. In the case of a line, there are two unit direction vectors (they are opposites), and neither is more natural than the other because a line doesn't have an "oriented" direction.